# Eval how to apply or condition C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<%# Eval("FeeStatus") == DBNull.Value OR 0 ? "UnPaid" : "Paid" %>
```

I simply want to say IF FeeStatus is null or 0 than print Unpaid .. what is syntax?
and what this condition is called i mean I am searching on net but don't know what to write ?

Comment: `Ternary Operator in C#`

Comment: Fairly certain you're doing comparison wrong. In an `or` statement you have to repeat the left-hand expression. This isn't C#'s `or` operator either, but I don't know if that might just be an ASP notation.

Comment: @RahulSingh I really don't understand what you're trying to say with that comment, and I'd be surprised if the OP does get it.

Comment: Re-opening, because as far as I can tell, the question isn't what `?` and `:` mean in general, but how they can be used here.

Comment: @hvd - Obviously that `OR 0` statement is wrong, probably OP is not aware of `ternary operator` so commented that.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel its not ASP. Besides everything inside `<%# %>` needs to be valid C#.

Comment: @Aron: can you clarify what kind of code I'm looking at? What environment do these `<%# %>` tags indicate?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel That's used in ASP.NET's ASPX pages for data binding, and the bits between `<%#` and `%>` must be a valid C# (or whatever language is used) expression.

Comment: Right okay. Too many ASP/ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC/ variants to keep track off. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel sorry. My bad. I meant to say, `OR` is not a part of the `ASP` nor `ASPX` view engine specification (since you said "but I don't know if that might just be an ASP notation"). In fact the server tags requires that the expression inside is a valid C# expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close but no cigar.

```
<%# Eval("FeeStatus") == DBNull.Value || (int) Eval("FeeStatus") == 0 ? "UnPaid" : "Paid" %>
```

OR

```
<%# new object[]{ DBNull.Value, 0 }.Contains(Eval("FeeStatus")) ? "UnPaid" : "Paid" %>
```

There is no `OR` operator in C#. Not to mention its not clear how you expect the `OR` operator would work in boolean logic.

Oh man...okay turns out you want this abomination.

```
<%# Eval("FeeStatus") as bool? ?? false ? "Paid" : "UnPaid" %>
```

Comment: its not checking the condition simply printing the paid

Comment: @miyanchau Probably because its the wrong type of zero. Try variations of 0I, Od, 0m etc... Is it a decimal?

Comment: it is a bit boolean type

Comment: @miyanchau You are messing with me right? Anyways, try `new object[]{ DBNull.Value, false }`. Actually you want this...`<%# Eval("FeeStatus") as bool? ?? false ? "Paid" : "UnPaid" %>`

Comment: why should I mess with you im just completing the characters to meet the minimum req of characters to post comment let me try this one

Comment: @miyanchau because the OP has `Eval("FeeStatus") == DBNull.Value OR 0` in it...never mind >_< I guess you don't understand...

Comment: <%# Eval("FeeStatus") as bool? ?? false ? "Paid" : "UnPaid" %> this works thanks @Aron handling NULL too .. awesome but how ? ?             I need to study more about it

Comment: @miyanchau check  hvd's comment on changing SQL schema and this silently failing...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably kept most readable by creating a helper function:

```
public bool IsPaid(object feeStatus) {
  return feeStatus != DBNull.Value && !(bool)feeStatus;
}
```

Then you can write:

```
<%# !IsPaid(Eval("FeeStatus")) ? "UnPaid" : "Paid" %>
```

C# doesn't have any native `x == (y or z)` form that translates to `x == y || x == z` except only evaluating `x` once, you need either a helper function or a helper variable for that.

You could write it out in full, if you don't mind calling `Eval` twice:

```
<%# Eval("FeeStatus") == DBNull.Value || !(bool)Eval("FeeStatus")? "UnPaid" : "Paid" %>
```

but this is harder to understand.

But if your `FeeStatus` is known to be one of `DBNull.Value`, `false`, or `true`, instead of comparing to `DBNull.Value` and `false`, you could just compare to `true`:

```
<%# Eval("FeeStatus").Equals(true) ? "Paid" : "UnPaid" %>
```

Comment: Thanks hvd .. but I dont want to use function it can't be done using ternary operators ? ..

Comment: @miyanchau Already added that to my answer: it's harder to understand, and pointlessly repeats an operation, so I don't recommend it, but yes, you can.

Comment: `<%# new object[]{ DBNull.Value, 0 }.Contains(Eval("FeeStatus")) ? "UnPaid" : "Paid" %>` will work but its ugly as sin.

Comment: @Aron Ha, yeah, you can use BCL functions instead of creating your own. You might even avoid LINQ and use the old-fashioned `Array.IndexOf(new object[] { DBNull.Value, 0 }, Eval("FeeStatus")) >= 0 ? "Unpaid" : "Paid"` :)

Comment: @hvd OMG Thats such a great idea! I think you need to add XML and a `.ToString()` :D

Comment: @hvd OMG...Turns out this is what OP wants `<%# Eval("FeeStatus") as bool? ?? false ? "Paid" : "UnPaid" %>`

Comment: @Aron Thanks for pointing to the comment saying that the type is `bool`. I've used `Eval("...") as T?` conversions in the past when the result would be known to be either `DBNull.Value`, or an instance of `T`, but stopped using that when this silently did the wrong thing when `Eval("...")` would start returning `short` instead of `int` due to database changes: no exception would be thrown, but it would evaluate to `null`. I personally would continue comparing to `DBNull.Value`, and if unequal, cast to `bool`. If the database changes, this causes an exception.

Comment: Honestly I always felt that `Eval` was an insanely bad API. Heck `ASP.Net WebForms` is just terrible.